Pygame Window Minimizes and Becomes Unresponsive
I'm encountering a persistent issue with a Pygame application that I'm developing. When I run my script, the Pygame window pops up briefly and then minimizes. When I try to restore the window, it shows "Not Responding" and remains unresponsive. This issue occurs even with very simple Pygame scripts.
I have already updated Python and attempted various troubleshooting steps, but the problem persists. Here is the code that I'm working with:
import pygame
import sys

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Set up the display
width, height = 800, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Simple Pygame Example")

# Define colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

# Set up the rectangle
rect_x, rect_y = width // 2, height // 2
rect_width, rect_height = 50, 50
rect_speed = 5

# Main loop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    # Get pressed keys
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        rect_x -= rect_speed
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        rect_x += rect_speed
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        rect_y -= rect_speed
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        rect_y += rect_speed

    # Fill the screen with white
    screen.fill(white)

    # Draw the rectangle
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, (rect_x, rect_y, rect_width, rect_height))

    # Update the display
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Cap the frame rate
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(60)


How are you running this program? I am able to run your program without issues when executing from VS code.

This is not a problem with your code, but with your system.

Please [edit] your question to include details about your operating system, python and pygame installation. Does your machine have any execution restrictions or other means of locking it down (e.g. for a school provided laptop). You could also try running your code on a cloud provider, e.g. replit.
